# using opencv in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimageview

1. I want to firstly choose a picture from my the local library, it shows on the UIImageView
2. and then I can use the opencv fuction UIImageToMat() to convert the UIImage to Mat and then I convert Mat to IPlImage to implement image processing algorithms(why I have to convert Mat to IplImage? Because most of my opencv image processing codes are based on IplImage).
3. So the choosen image shows on the UIImageView, if I want to do some image processing things, I'll first convert the UIImage to IplImage, process it and then convert IplImage to UIImage again. That's the way I use opencv to do image processing things.
4. But the problem is when I want to process the chosen picture from the local library, something strange happens:
   the original picture is:
   [image]

and then I want to use opencv to let some columns of this picture to be blue and some rows to be red, but the result is:
[image]

the implementation code is:
[image]

I don't know why this happens, the picture obviously lost many important features during the opencv image processing process.(I just want some columns to be blue and some rows to be red.).Why this happened?